# Cypher Query for all nodes that have shared relationships to the 2 or more sub-nodes?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Created a GraphGist to help explain my issue:

https://gist.github.com/bconneen/e5c66e26883958c81ae6fc5c607fdfa9

**Consider the following Neo4J model:**

```
Applicant(firstName, lastName, uniqueId)
Phone(number)
IpAddress(ip)
BankAccount(routing,account)

Applicant--has->Phone,
Applicant--has->IpAddress,
Applicant--has-->BankAccount
```

All nodes are created using merge.  So if we process 100,000 applications relationships will be created where occasionally more than 1 Applicant shares one or more of Phone, IpAddress, BankAccount.

I want the nodes returned to be when 2 or more Applicants share 2 or more Phone, IpAddress or BankAccount. I want to write a query that returns All Applicants and their shared relationships. That meet the criteria.

**Example:**

Applicant(John Smith) has Phone (555-555-5555), has ipAddress (127.0.0.1), has BankAccount (ABCDEF)

Applicant(Jane Doe) has Phone(222-222-2222, has ipAddress (127.0.0.1), has BankAccount (ABCDEF)

Applicant(Steve Zahn) has Phone(555-555-5555), has ipAddress(127.2.2.2), has BankAccount(GHJKD)

Applicant(James Clay) has Phone(444-444-4444), has ipAddress(129.3.3.3), has BankAccount(ZYXWVU)

**Query for All Applicants that share 2 or more Phone, IpAddress or Bank:**

Applicant(John Smith) has Phone (555-555-5555), has ipAddress (127.0.0.1), has BankAccount (ABCDEF)

Applicant(Jane Doe) has Phone(222-222-2222, has ipAddress (127.0.0.1), has BankAccount (ABCDEF)

**Query for All Applicants that share 1 or more Phone, IpAddress or Bank:**

Applicant(John Smith) has Phone (555-555-5555), has ipAddress (127.0.0.1), has BankAccount (ABCDEF)

Applicant(Jane Doe) has Phone(222-222-2222, has ipAddress (127.0.0.1), has BankAccount (ABCDEF)

Applicant(Steve Zahn) has Phone(555-555-5555), has ipAddress(127.2.2.2), has BankAccount(GHJKD)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the data from your gist:

**Query for all applicants that share 2 or more phone, ipaddress or bank**

```
MATCH (applicant:Applicant)-[r]->(subelement)<-[r2]-(other:Applicant)
WITH applicant, other, collect(subelement) AS overlap 
WHERE id(applicant) > id(other) AND size(overlap) > 1
RETURN applicant, other, overlap
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can I ask a coupe of clarifying questions? A) What does this part accomplish: "WHERE id(applicant) > id(other)"?  B) If i'm understanding it correctly it only returns 2 Applicants. Even if there are more than 2 sharing the same information?

Comment: Thanks again for the help. I've submitted the Gist here: http://portal.graphgist.org/graph_gists/6de21406-ca93-47ff-ab66-526e73ea6c12

Comment: it excludes duplicates